# Python scramble function is too slow (Codewars 'Scramblies')

Tags: python

> Complete the function `scramble(str1, str2)` that returns true if a
> portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise
> returns false.

I've written the below solution that passes all the tests:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    for char in s2:
        if char not in s1:
            return False
        else:
            s1 = s1.replace(char, '', 1)
    return True
```

But I am getting a 'Timed Out' error when I run the code in Codewars. Is there something I can do to further optimize this code?

Comment: Maybe [codereview.se] will be a better fit for such question...

Comment: Try to refine your algorithm. Think of it like that: when do you return true? If all the letters in `str2` have (at least) the same count in `str1`

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for this question, but to get you started: what must be true about the _distinct character-frequency pairs_ in `str1` and `str2` so that those in one can be rearranged into the other?

Comment: The function is `O(|s1| * |s2|)`: `if char not in s1:` and `s1.replace(char, '', 1)` traverse the entirety of `s1` inside your loop for every character of `s2`. Look for a linear or solution using a dict or frequency counter.

Comment: @Tomerikoo returning true is kind of opposite to exitcodes

Comment: @FlashThunder not sure I understand...

Comment: Thank you all, this is very helpful! I used Counter() to redo the problem and passed with no Timed Out errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for c in set(s2):
        if s1.count(c) < s2.count(c):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This code is only marginally more efficient than the OP's. The `str.count` method has to do a linear scan on each string for each unique char in `s2`.